# Disable client SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, mqtt

I have generated client key certificate on self signed secure `Mosquitto` server. I have copied CA and client certificate with client key into client machine. Client subscription runs fine:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.8 -t sensor --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -p 8883 -d
```

But what if somebody hack my client machine and will get credentials. How I can disable this certificate in server machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if your client certificate's private key is compromised, the CA should revoke your certificate and inform the relying parties via [CRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list)s or [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol).

Mosquitto only understands CRLs, using the `crlfile`option.

You must download this manually to a local [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) file and point Mosquitto to this file with the above option.

Comment: How does this `crlfile` should look like? Should I copy all failed certificates into it?

Comment: A CRL (as pointed to by `crlfile`) is a file generated by your CA.  The CRL format is defined in RFC5280 - you cannot simply copy certificates into a list.  Speak to your CA admins.